# GC Overhead limit exceeded in WSO2 EI 6.6

Tags: java-8, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

In WSO2 EI 6.6, proxy stopped working abruptly. upon analyzing observed an error in the wso2 carbon log "GC Overhead limit exceeded", after this error nothing happening in the EI.

Proxy logic is to get the data from Sql server table and form an xml and send it to an external API. Proxy runs every 5 mins interval and in every interval maximum of 5 records will be pushed to an API.

After restarting the wso2 carbon services, proxy are started working. currently we are restarting the services every 3 days to avoid this issue.

Need to know how to identify the potential issue and resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

This mean the JVM has run out of allocated memory. There can be many reasons for this. For example, if you haven't allocated enough memory to the JVM you can easily run out of memory. If that's not the case you need to analyze a memory dump and see what's occupying the memory causing it to fill up.

Generally, when you see the mentioned error the JVM automatically creates a heap dump(heap-dump.hprof) in the `<EI_HOME>/repository/logs` directory. You can try analyzing the dump to find the root cause. If the server doesn't generate a memory dump, manually take a memory dump when it's occupied than the expected level and analyze it.

Comment: Facing same issue with EI 6.5.0 , memory allocated is 4000MB and very low load on the apis. Can the issue be due to the Java version in use? Note : heap-dump.hprof was not generated